# Add tweet button on wordpress blog

Tags: twitter, wordpress

I have been trying to put twitter's new tweet button on my wordpress blog. I have tried code provided on official twitter website, and couple of wordpress plugins to add tweet button on the blog. But on every try I am running into same issue. When I click on tweet button it goes to the twitter website but says

url' parameter does not contain a valid URL.

Could anyone please suggest me the way out for the same. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-tweet-button/

It works fine for me, and has couple of options to choose from.

Comment: hey thanks Ruel for your response, I have tried to use this plugin but still stuck with the same issue, I suspect I am making a smiliar mistake anywhere. Could you please help me.

Answer (score -1):

hmmm.....I don't know why this is happening but I think you are using a local server and your url contains some ip address so that when you are clicking on the tweet button it will take your ip address also to connect with tweer site.

So it make url invalid, work on live site I think it will work.all the best.....